# Content type and site column re-usability inside the Flat structure

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, site-collection, modern-experience, hub-site

I wrote this question about 6 months ago about the ability to reuse content types and site columns among site collections that are connected to a hub site in the Flat structure world [Migrating our on-premises sub-sites to be modern site collections. how we will be managing the content types and site columns](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/253729/migrating-our-on-premises-sub-sites-to-be-modern-site-collections-how-we-will-b). I were comparing the flat structure with the sub-sites appraoch, where in the sub-sites appraoch we can manage the site columns and content types at the root site and reuse all the site columns and content types automatically inside the sub-sites. so after 6 months have any improvement or are there any approaches inside sharepoint online that can allow us to  facilitate content types and site columns re-usability inside the flat structure? or the same old case applies, that we should use power-shell to manage the same content types and site columns among site collection in the flat structure?
of course i am excluding the option to use content type hub sites to enable content type re-usability inside hub sites, as  content type hub sites appraoch is very classic/old approach that we should not use with the hub site. as if i have the decision to use the sub-sites approaches or to use hub-sites with content type hubs, i will go with the sub-sites appraoch..
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Content Type Hub is the current solution for pushing CT/Site Columns to all sites, Modern and Classic.

The alternative is to use a Site Design script and reapply it to all appropriate sites when a CT/Site Column changes.

Comment: but Content Type Hub is very classic and old, and when we link a modern site with the classic Content Type Hub, the link will be very complicated/strong to remove later on,, if MS offers modern Content Type Hub i would use them with modern sites inside the flat structure.. but i do not think it is valid/reliable/wise to have modern site collections inside the modern flat structure that have a strong connection to the old/classic Content Type Hub.. so i will use power-shell to manage and reuse my CT and site columns,unless/until MS provide CT re-usability inside hub sites.

Comment: Your reply makes little sense. If you want tenant-wide content types/site columns, use the CT Hub. If not, manually provision them on the appropriate sites.

Comment: But I mean even if i want a tenant-wide content types and site columns will not use the content type hub sites, as CT hubs are considered as classic appraoch, and we are been advised by Microsoft to use the modern sites and flat experience as all the future improvement are been targeted to modern sites.. so it does not make sense (at-least to me) to have modern sites which have a strong link to the classic CT hub sites.. i am sure you know if u link a modern site with the classic  CT hubs, then there will be a very strong link which can not be removed ...

Comment: CT Hub is not designed to be used as a day to day site. Again, if you want tenant-wide CTs/Site Columns, you *must* use a CT Hub unless you're willing to manually maintain them. Don't get hung up on the modern site -- that's for sites end users will be interacting with. The CT Hub still works with modern sites. This may be a scenario where you're not thrilled with the answer, but that is what is available to you today.

Comment: i did not get what do you exactly mean by `Don't get hung up on the modern site -- that's for sites end users will be interacting with`... still as an admin i can create modern sites + on new office 365 tenants the root  site will be a modern communication site.. so modern sites not only be created by end users, but they need to be created by admins + it is the new root site template... i still do not find my self linking modern sites with content type hubs ...

Comment: Create the CT Hub as-is and push out your CTs. It will propagate to all of your Site Collections, classic or modern. You're hung up on the fact that the CT Hub isn't a modern feature. I think you need to just understand that no everything is a modern feature but they still work with modern sites. Why don't you just try it? It does work, I'm using it. Since this conversation is getting too long, please ask a new question or edit your question so someone else can come along to answer it.

Comment: yes i know it will work and i already test it even with modern pages.. but let say MS decided to dispose or depreciate classic sites... then what will happen to our Content type hub,, which all the modern site will be relying on ?  just put your self on my side.. if we want to follow an appraoch like using modern sites, then we will need to use it till the end

Comment: Microsoft has no such plams. Your fears are unfounded.